# Make a function that produces a list of file names with a common prefix and a unique integer as the final character

Tags: python, for-loop, format, string-formatting

Basically, I want to create a function of some specified range (let's say 7) that produces a list like this:

```
list_of_filenames = ['my_file1.json', 'my_file2.json', 'my_file3.json', 'my_file4.json', 'my_file5.json,' 'my_file6.json', 'my_file7.json']
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
def make_files_list(file_prefix):
    filenames_list = []
    for file in range(7):
        file = '{0}'.format(file_prefix)+ str(1) + '.json'
        filenames_list.append(file)
    return filenames_list

final_files_list = make_files_list('my_file')
```

But of course, I just get a list of all the same filenames with '1' as the final character, like:

```
list_of_filenames = ['my_file1.json', 'my_file1.json', 'my_file1.json', 'my_file1.json', 'my_file1.json,' 'my_file1.json', 'my_file1.json']
```

I understand why my function isn't working right, but I don't know how to fix it so it adds subsequent integers to each subsequent list item.

Comment: It should be `str(file)`, not `str(1)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
def make_files_list(file_prefix):
    filenames_list = []
    for file in range(7):
        file = '{0}'.format(file_prefix)+ str(1) + '.json' <--- you always call str(1)
        filenames_list.append(file)
    return filenames_list

final_files_list = make_files_list('my_file')
```

--

Try this one instead

```
def make_files_list(file_prefix):
    filenames_list = []
    for x in range(7):
        file = '{0}'.format(file_prefix)+ str(x) + '.json'
        filenames_list.append(file)
    return filenames_list

final_files_list = make_files_list('my_file')
```